# How to check or validate if URL exists - CORS error returned?

Tags: javascript, validation, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm trying to check/validate if a URL exists, via JavaScript.  And I've found some code which should work.

However, I've ran into the CORS error.  Seems my request keeps getting blocked:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.co.uk/' (redirected
>   from 'http://www.google.co.uk/') from origin 'null' has been blocked
>   by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
>   the requested resource.

How can I resolve this with JS, with no server side code?  I want to handle this entirely on the front-end/client-side:

```
var MrChecker = new XMLHttpRequest(),
CheckThisUrl = "http://www.google.co.uk";

// Opens the file and specifies the method (get)
// Asynchronous is true
MrChecker.open('get', CheckThisUrl, true);

//check each time the ready state changes
//to see if the object is ready
MrChecker.onreadystatechange = checkReadyState;

function checkReadyState() {
    if (MrChecker.readyState === 4) {

        //check to see whether request for the file failed or succeeded
        if ((MrChecker.status == 200) || (MrChecker.status == 0)) {
          console.log(CheckThisUrl + ' page is exixts');
        }
        else {
          console.log(CheckThisUrl + ' not exists');
        return;
        }
    }
}
MrChecker.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, which encourages the use of **fetch() API**, which bypasses the CORS error/block.

However, I wasn't sure if there are any cons/disadvantages to use this approach?

It seems it does what I need it to do.... to check whether a URL exists on the internet or not:

```
 const url = "https://www.google.com/"; 
 $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp', 
      statusCode: {
        200: function() {
          console.log( "status code 200 returned" );
        },
        404: function() {
          console.log( "status code 404 returned" );
        }
      },
      error:function(){
          console.log("Error");
      }
 });
```